# How can I change what to be indexed on google by using WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo

I am using WooCommerce plugin together with SEO by Yoast on my wordpress site.

At the moment the indexation is working properly BUT there is one issue. The text that is indexed is the long product description and not the short product description that I want.

My question: How do I change in my wordpress site to index the short product description.

Note: The product descriptions I write in wp-admin>woocommerce>products and then in the specific products.

[URL to site](http://www.feelhome.se/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a specific URL? That's not enough info. Out of the box, Yoast will make it look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nokia Lumia 930 - Your Site Name
yoursite.com/nokia-lumia-930
This is the Nokia Lumia 930 and it's very nice. It's got a pretty good camera.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Line (1) is product name & site name. Line (3) is short product description.

One thing you should know is that Google **doesn't guarantee** your product description will be used in its SERPs.

Comment: Where in my website can I change what should say in the short product description?

There is no specific link.. but try this http://www.feelhome.se/produkt/la-habana-skyline/

My website works like this, you can write in 2 texts:
1. One short text, that is to the right of the product image
2. One longer text, that is below the image

The website indexes the longer text, but I don't want that. I want it to index the shorter text that is to right of the picture

Comment: If you're running Yoast SEO, you get a "Yoast SEO" edit block when you're editing a product. That's where you can set the title and meta description. But as I said before, it doesn't mean that Google or Bing will use it. In both cases they may use snippets from the long product description instead.

Comment: Glad to help. Can you please mark the answer as correct so others can find it as well? :-)